# PySpark computing correlation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I want to use `pyspark.mllib.stat.Statistics.corr` function to compute correlation between two columns of `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` object. `corr` function expects to take an `rdd` of `Vectors` objects. How do I translate a column of `df['some_name']` to `rdd` of `Vectors.dense` object?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There should be no need for that. For numerical you can compute correlation directly using `DataFrameStatFunctions.corr`:

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0)]).toDF(["x", "y"])
df1.stat.corr("x", "y")
# -1.0
```

otherwise you can use `VectorAssembler`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.columns, outputCol="features")
assembler.transform(df).select("features").flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

Comment: It supports only pearson.

Comment: Trying VectorAssembler, I first got ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flatMap'). Then appended .rdd to select('features'). Now getting (Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 48.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure), when collecting the returned RDD.

Comment: The solution found here helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831874/how-to-get-correlation-matrix-values-pyspark

Comment: this returns a matrix without columns names. Anyway to assign column names respectively? Also, can we convert it into some different form so it can be exported?

I know if converted to pandas DF colum names can be provided but converting is slow :/

Answer (score 7):

`df.stat.corr("column1","column2")`

Answer (score 4):

```
from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseMatrix, Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Loading Data with more than 50 features
newdata = spark.read.csv("sample*.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=newdata.columns, 
outputCol="features",handleInvalid='keep')
df = assembler.transform(newdata).select("features")

# correlation will be in Dense Matrix
correlation = Correlation.corr(df,"features","pearson").collect()[0][0]

# To convert Dense Matrix into DataFrame
rows = correlation.toArray().tolist()
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows,newdata.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out:

```
v1 = df.flatMap(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x[col_idx_1]))
v2 = df.flatMap(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x[col_idx_2]))
```